# Short way for conics and quadrics classification and special cases

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections, quadrics

I’m studying linear algebra, and for conic sections we studied that we can get the canonical form of a conic without having to explicitly calculate the transformations and applying them on the equation of the conic.

- *Note: the way we do it is by using orthogonal invariants and their correlation with eigenvalues: if you’re familiar with this method you can skip the first section, which explains it*.

**METHOD FOR FINDING DIAGONAL/CANONICAL FORM OF CONIC WITH ORTHOGONAL INVARIANTS**

Let $Γ$ be a given conic with an associated $3x3$ matrix $$\overline{A}= \begin{pmatrix}A & \underline{b}\\\ \underline{b}^t & c \end{pmatrix} $$ where $A$ is the $2x2$ matrix of the terms of degree 2, $\underline{b}$ is the $2x1$ vector of the linear terms and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is the constant term. Its diagonal/canonical form $Γ’$ (except if it’s a parabola, but I will get to that later) will have a canonical matrix associated $$\overline{A’}= \begin{pmatrix}α & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & β & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & γ\end{pmatrix} $$ where $α$, $β$, $λ$ are the eigenvalues of $\overline{A’}$ (in particular $α$ and $β$ are the eigenvalues of $A’$).

We know that we can diagonalize a conic just with rototranslations (which are isometries), and we also know that $tr(A)$, $det(A)$, $det\left(\overline{A}\right)$ don’t change if we apply a rototranslation on the conic $Γ$ associated to $\overline{A}$ (they’re called ortogonal invariants). Thus,

$$
\begin{cases}
tr(A)=tr(A’) \\ 
det(A)=det(A’) \\ 
det(\overline{A})= det(\overline{A’})
\end{cases}
$$

But since $tr(A’)=α+β$,$det(A’)=αβ$, $det\left(\overline{A’}\right)=αβγ$, then we have

$$\begin{cases}
tr(A)=α+β \\
det(A)=αβ \\
det(\overline{A})=αβγ \\
\end{cases}$$

And we can calculate the eigenvalues (and thus, the canonical form $Γ’$ of $Γ$) just by calculating the ortogonal invariants of $A$ and solving the system above, without having to do all the long calculations that we would do by applying the traslation and the transformation.

**Q1**

Let $$\overline{B’}= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & -b \\\ 0 & -b & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ be the canonical form of a parabola, or, as an equation, $x^2-2βy=0$. Note that $b$ is not an eigenvalue of neither $B'$ or $\overline{B'}$, so it's not a greek letter (eigenvalues are denoted with greek letters in this question).

Is it correct to say that, given a general equation of a conic $\Gamma$ (with associated matrix $\overline{B}$ and quadratic part $B$) that we know is a parabola, we can find its canonical form by solving the system:

$$\begin{cases}
tr(A)=α \\
det(A)=0 \\
det(\overline{A})=-b^2 \\
\end{cases}$$

**METHOD FOR FINDING DIAGONAL/CANONICAL FORM OF QUADRIC WITH ORTHOGONAL INVARIANTS**

- *Note: as for conic sections, if you're familiar with orthogonal invariants, just skip this.*

If, in a similar way to conics, $\overline{A}$ is the $4x4$ matrix associated to a quadric $Γ$ and $A$ is the $3x3$ matrix of its quadratic terms, then the orthogonal invariants are

1. $tr(A)$
2. $det(A)$
3. $c$=the sum of the principal minors of order 2 of $A$
4. $det(\overline{A})$

If the diagonal form $\overline{A’}$ (associated to $Γ’$, obtained with rototranslations from $Γ$) is $diag(α, β, γ, δ)$, then
$$\begin{cases}
tr(A) =α+β+γ \\
c = αβ + βγ + αγ\\
det(A) = αβγ \\
det(\overline{A})=αβγδ
\end{cases}
$$

But paraboloids and cilinders have canonical forms that contain linear terms, so we have to find some coefficients that are not eigenvalues.

**Q2**

For paraboloids, which should have canonical form $2bz=\alpha x^2+\beta y^2$:

$$\overline{A}= \begin{pmatrix}\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & \beta & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -b\\\ 0 & 0 & -b & 0\end{pmatrix} $$

the system to find the canonical form should be

$$\begin{cases}
tr(A) =α+β \\
c = αβ\\
det(A) = 0 \\
det(\overline{A})=-b^2αβ
\end{cases}
$$

Is it correct?

**Q3**

For cilinders with a parabola as a cross section, which should have canonical form $2bz=\alpha x^2$, but we can divide for b (since $b=0$) and it becomes $2z=\alpha ' x^2$:

$$\overline{A}= \begin{pmatrix}\alpha ' & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$

the system to find the canonical form should be

$$\begin{cases}
tr(A) =α' \\
c = 0\\
det(A) = 0 \\
det(\overline{A})=0
\end{cases}
$$

Is it correct?

- Note that **Q2** and **Q3** is the analogous of **Q1**, but for quadrics: I'm trying to apply a similar method to the one showed in **Q1** to find the canonical form of paraboloids and cilinders with parabola as a section, without having to do all the long calculations that I would do by applying the transformations

**LAST DOUBT**

I’m gonna take the paraboloid as an example.

Is it the same to take, as a canonical form, ($case (1)$) the equation $$2bz=\alpha x^2+\beta y^2 \iff \overline{A}= \begin{pmatrix}\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & \beta & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -b\\\ 0 & 0 & -b & 0\end{pmatrix} \iff \begin{cases}
tr(A) =α+β \\
c = αβ\\
det(A) = 0 \\
det(\overline{A})=-b^2αβ
\end{cases}
(1)
$$

and then dividing the equation by $b$ or ($case (2)$) using, as a canonical form, the equation $$ 2z=\alpha x^2+\beta y^2 \iff
 \overline{A}= \begin{pmatrix}\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & \beta & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \iff
\begin{cases}
tr(A) =α+β \\
c = αβ\\
det(A) = 0 \\
det(\overline{A})=-αβ
\end{cases}
(2)
$$.

Do both methods bring to the same result? If not, is it that they’re both correct canonical forms but they’re different, or is it that the first needs still to be transformated, or does the first bring to a wrong paraboloid?

And does this apply also, for example, for using the canonical form $αx^2+βy^2+γz^2=δ$ instead of $αx^2+βy^2+γz^2=1$ for ellipsoids?

Comment: Do you know where I can read about this sort of thing?

Comment: @JosephHarrison if you’re talking about the method I’m describing, I found it in my professor’s textbook, and it’s in italian. Probably, if you want to search something like this the keywords should be “quadrics” (note that it’s a “linear algebra and geometry” course, but we mainly use matrices, because we do very little geometry), “canonical/diagonal form of quadrics”. Also, studying quadrics comes after studying conic sections, and they both are studied as applications of the spectral theorem on symmetric matrices (in the context of quadratic forms).

Comment: @JosephHarrison Also, note that i’m studying computer science. From what I’ve seen, in maths you (obviously) study geometry much more in depth and you study quadrics as surfaces with a lot of geometry, so I can’t really understand much of the stuff that I find online on quadrics because they are really “geometric-imprinted”. The only online notes in english that study quadrics pretty close to how I studied them are https://web.northeastern.edu/dummit/teaching_sp20_4571/4571_lecture_30_quadratic_forms_1.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your response and for finding me that reference! I have studied conics quite a bit but not quadrics in detail. I am not familiar with the language that you use (rototranslations, orthogonal invariants) and it seems as though there is an interesting theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your equations are correct. A general approach to this problem is the following.

**Preliminary observations**

When you change basis on an $n$-dimensional real vector space, there is an invertible matrix $P$ (the so called "change of basis matrix") which expresses the relation between "old" and new coordinates:

$$\mathbf x=P\mathbf{x'}$$

for $\mathbf x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R ^n$.

Explicitly,

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=p_{11}x_1'+\dots+p_{1n}x_n' \\
\vdots \\
x_n=p_{n1}x_1'+\dots+p_{nn}x_n' 
\end{cases}
$$

This fact is called a linear change of coordinates. Notice that in this way the $n$-tuple $(0,\dots,0)$ corresponds to the same point with respect to both coordinates. In geometric terms, this change of coordinates keep fixed a point. In order to allow also translations, we take into account *affine* change of coordinates, of the form

$$\mathbf x=P\mathbf{x'}+\mathbf v \qquad (*)$$

for $P$ an invertible $n\times n$ real matrix and $\mathbf v\in \mathbb R^n$

Explicitly,

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=p_{11}x_1'+\dots+p_{1n}x_n'+v_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_n=p_{n1}x_1'+\dots+p_{nn}x_n' +v_n
\end{cases}
$$

Notice moreover that if we accept the convention of representing any point of coordinates $\mathbf x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with the $(n+1)$-tuple $\overline{\mathbf{x}}=(x_1,\dots,x_n,1)$, then  (*) can be written as

$$\overline{\mathbf{x}}=\overline{P} \overline{\mathbf{x}'} $$

where $\overline P=\begin{pmatrix}
P & \mathbf v \\
\mathbf 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

(if you compute the row-column product you will see the equivalence).

**Affine orthogonal equivalence of quadrics**

Consider a quadric in $\mathbb R^n$, defined by (with your notation):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & x_n & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A & \mathbf b \\
\mathbf b^T & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & \dots & x_n & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In shorter notation: $\overline{\mathbf x}^T \overline A \overline{\mathbf x}$

After an affine change of coordinates of the form $\overline{\mathbf{x}}=\overline{P} \overline{\mathbf{x}}' $

the equation becomes

$$\overline{\mathbf x '}^T\overline{P}^T  \overline A \overline P \overline{\mathbf x '}$$

i.e. the matrices $\overline A$ and $\overline A'=\overline{P}^T  \overline A \overline P$ define the same quadric up to a suitable affine change of coordinates

However, we are interested in some specific affine changes of coordinates, those that preserve metric properties ("rigid motions"). This is accomplished requiring the matrix $P$ to be not only invertible but also *orthogonal*.

Therefore we will consider equivalent the quadrics defined by $\overline A$ and $\overline{P}^T  \overline A \overline P$ if $\overline P$ is of the form:

$$
\overline P= \begin{pmatrix}
P & \mathbf v \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with $P$ an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix (you could make further distinction in requiring $P$ *special orthogonal*... but the key facts are the same).

In particular, we look for canonical forms, i.e. a set of quadrics such that any other is equivalent in the sense above specified to one of the canonical ones.

Let's see how to find them:

By the spectral theorem applied to the symmetric matrix $A$, we can choose an orthonormal basis (hence an orthogonal change of basis matrix $P$) such that $A'$ is diagonal (i.e. $A'=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$). Moreover, completing the squares (I skip the details, but I can add them if you wish), we can cancel with suitable traslations the linear terms associated to the coordinates such that $\lambda_i\neq 0$ (e.g. in $x^2+y^2-2x=0$ we write $(x-1)^2+y^2-1=0$...). If both the linear and constant terms disappear, we are done (type (i)). If only the linear terms disappear but not the constant one, we normalize the constant $c$ to 1 (type (ii)). If some linear term survives (consider e.g. $x^2-y=0$) and thus at least one $\lambda_i$ is zero, we can still manage to change the coordinates in such a way that there is only one linear term and no constant (type (iii)).

Therefore, for any symmetric $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix $\overline A$ defining a quadric, there is an orthogonal affine change of coordinates such that the quadric is represented by $\overline A'$ which has one of the following forms

- (type (i)) $\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1 &  & & \\
  &\ddots & & \\
  & & \lambda_n  & \\
  & & & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
- (type (ii)) $\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1 &  & & \\
  &\ddots & & \\
  & & \lambda_n  & \\
  & & & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
- (type (iii)) $\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1 &  & & &\\
  &\ddots & & & \\
  & & \lambda_{n-1} & & \\
  & & & 0 & 1 \\
  & & & 1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $

with $\lambda_i\in\mathbb R$ possibly equal to 0.

In the case $n=2$ we have the usual canonical forms of conic curves: type (i) corresponds to degenerate conics, type (ii) to ellipses and hyperbolas, type (iii) to parabolas (assuming $\lambda_i\neq 0$ in the last two cases, otherwise they reduce to degenerate conics).

**Orthogonal invariants**

It turns out that some quantities that depend on the matrix $\overline A$ are invariant under orthogonal affine transformations. Therefore they can be used to compute the coefficients of the canonical form exactly as done in the question.

In particular

1. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is invariant under orthogonal affine transformations

*Proof:* If $P$ is orthogonal, $P^T A P=P^{-1}AP$, thus it is *similar* to $A$ and they have the same characteristic polynomial.

This implies that the *coefficients* of the characteristic polynomial concide. In the case $n=2$ they are determinant and trace. For bigger values of $n$, the other coefficients are expressible as suitable functions of the principal minors (as done in the question).

2. The determinant of $\overline A$ is invariant under orthogonal affine transformations

*Proof:* $\det(\overline{P}^T  \overline A \overline P)=\det(\overline P ^T)\det(\overline A)\det(\overline P)=\det(\overline A)$ since $\det(\overline P)=\det(P)=1$.

Therefore you can always use those invariants in order to find the canonical form of the quadric.

A possible way, if you already know that the quadric is non degenerate (i.e. $\det(\overline A)\neq 0$), is the following:

1. If $\det(A)=0$ (this is the case for parabolas and paraboloids), the canonical form is of type (iii), and the $n-1$ coefficients $\lambda_i$ can be found using $\det(\overline A)$ and the coefficients of characteristic polynomial. For conics they are determinant and trace, for quadrics in three dimensional space you consider also the sum of principal $2\times 2$ minors (that is what you called $c$) and for bigger $n$ you compute the other coefficients in a similar fashion).
2. If $\det(A)\neq 0$, the canonical form is of type (ii), and the $n$ coefficients $\lambda_i$ can be found using the coefficients of characteristic polynomial and $\det(\overline A)$.

The practical way is exactly the one you perfomed in your examples. However you sometimes employed canonical forms that are not completely canonical, e.g. for the paraboloid, where your coefficient $b$ can be normalized to 1.

For further reference, you can look at Berger, *Geometry II*, chapters 13 and 15.

Comment: Excellent answer thanks, but I have some questions: you said that the metric canonical form I wrote for the paraboloid (for example) is not completely canonical. Is it because from $Γ_1: αx^2+βy^2-2bz=0$ I can divide by $b$, or is it because I should really use the canonical form $Γ_2: αx^2+βy^2-2z=0$? And is taking $Γ_1$ and dividing by $b$ the same as getting $Γ_2$? Because the thing that seems strange to me is that the canonical form of a paraboloid $Γ$ should be different if it is of type $Γ_1’: \frac{α}{b}x^2+\frac{β}{b}y^2-2z=0$ or of type $Γ_2$, because $\frac{α}{b}x^2≠αx^2$ and…

Comment: … $\frac{β}{b}y^2≠βy^2$.

Comment: I added more details to my question mentioned in the comments so it’s more clear (see **LAST DOUBT** section): if you can help me with this last thing I would be very glad.