# Coefficients of characteristic polynomial and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, quadrics

Let $A$ be a $3x3$ symmetric (thus, orthogonally diagonalizable) real matrix.
We know that its characteristic polynomial is (in the variable $λ$) $$-λ^3 + tr(A)λ^2-cλ+det(A)$$
where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is the sum of the principal minors of order 2 of A.
If $α$, $β$, $γ$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ (not necessarily different), we know that we can write $tr(A)$ and $det(A)$ as sum and product (respectively) of the eigenvalues, and this is sometimes useful to calculate the eigenvalues:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
tr(A) =α+β+γ \\ 
det(A) = αβγ \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to express $c$ as equal to an expression with eigenvalues in it, so that we can use a system of the form $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
tr(A) =α+β+γ \\ 
det(A) = αβγ \\
c = ? 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

and we can calculate the 3 eigenvalues?

**APPENDIX**

My purpose is to use this to diagonalize the $3x3$ matrix of the quadratic terms of a quadric surface (the “complete” matrix is a $4x4$).
See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620431/short-way-for-conics-and-quadrics-classification-and-special-cases).

Comment: Actually $tr(A)$ is the coefficient of $\lambda$.

Comment: @EDX ok corrected, apparently the source I’m using has some mistakes in it

Comment: Hint: what is the sum of the principal second order minors of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @blargoner $c=αβ + αγ + βγ$, is it correct? Edit: thanks for the hint, just saw answer

Comment: @EDX That is not correct. In general up to sign sum of $p$-th order principal minors associated with $\lambda^{n-p}$.

Comment: @blargoner can you please explain what isn’t correct? the comment or the answer of EDX?

Comment: The comment about trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes :

$$ c=\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha $$

In general those polynoms (for diagonalized matrix) will be Newton's polynom for multi-nominal expression (number of indeteminate will be the size of the matrix).